# How to build a .a file correctly (KMM)

Tags: sql, kotlin, terminal, kotlin-multiplatform, sqlcipher

We need to include SQLCipher in our KMM project without using Cocoapods. This involves building a **libSQLCipher.a**.
I was able to this in terminal with these commands:

```
./configure --enable-tempstore=yes --with-crypto-lib=commoncrypto CFLAGS="
-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1
-DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=3 
-DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_CC
-DSQLITE_SOUNDEX 
-DSQLITE_THREADSAFE 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT3 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4_UNICODE61 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 
-DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 
-DHAVE_USLEEP=1 
-DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=99999"
LDFLAGS="/usr/local/Cellar/openssl@1.1 /1.1.1l_1/lib/libcrypto.a"

make sqlite3.c

`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find clang` -x c -target arm64-apple-ios8.0 -isysroot `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path` -fmodules -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -fstrict-aliasing -fembed-bitcode-marker -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4_UNICODE61 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_CC -DHAVE_USLEEP=1 -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=99999 -DNDEBUG -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -DSQLITE_SOUNDEX -DSQLITE_THREADSAFE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT3 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_STAT4 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_COLUMN_METADATA -DSQLITE_ENABLE_MEMORY_MANAGEMENT -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS4_UNICODE61 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3_PARENTHESIS -DSQLITE_ENABLE_UNLOCK_NOTIFY -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 -DSQLCIPHER_CRYPTO_CC -DHAVE_USLEEP=1 -DSQLITE_MAX_VARIABLE_NUMBER=99999 -fno-objc-arc -fmodule-name=SQLCipher -Oz -fno-common -c sqlite3.c -o sqlite3.o

`xcrun --sdk iphoneos --find libtool` -static -arch_only arm64 -syslibroot `xcrun --sdk iphoneos --show-sdk-path` -o libSQLCipher.a sqlite3.o
```

I bring the **libSQLCipher.a** into Android studio, and set it up per the instructions on the KMM website, create the **.def** file, link it up, add to **build.gradle** etc.
I can access methods such as ***sql3_open()***, which is great.
However, I cannot access ***sqlite3_key(), sqlite3_key_v2(), sqlite3_rekey(), sqlite3_rekey_v2(), sqlite3_activate_see()***.

I noticed in the .h file, these are here:

```
/* BEGIN SQLCIPHER */
#ifdef SQLITE_HAS_CODEC
 // sqlite3_key(), sqlite3_key_v2(), sqlite3_rekey(), sqlite3_rekey_v2(), 
sqlite3_activate_see() methods are defined here
#endif
/* END SQLCIPHER */
```

SQLCipher website says to include **SQLITE_HAS_CODEC** in the build config, which it looks like I am doing. So I'm really lost as to why I cannot access these methods.

Bit of a long winded question but really hope somebody here has some advice on it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin/Native's `cinterop` tool should have all compiler options specified explicitly to "see" the header the same way as your compiler did when building the library. To specify the compiler options, please use the DSL as described in [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-dsl-reference.html#cinterops).

In general, something like that should work:

```
...
kotlin {
    iosArm64 { // Replace with a target you need.
        compilations.getByName("main") {
            val myInterop by cinterops.creating {
...
                compilerOpts("-DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1")
...
        }
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Wow, I could kiss you, been struggling with this for days  
Thanks for the help!